# How to create user in phpmyadmin to connect two servers?

Tags: server, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

IP my Website: `192.168.19.33` and IP Database server is: `192.168.19.41`.

How to create user account in `phpmyadmin` for the connection between the two servers?

And how to edit this setting:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=website
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

to this setting:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.19.41
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=website
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Why do you need to connect to two servers? Your database only resides on *one* server.

Comment: @JohnConde Hi, i have 5 servers and need one database server, but i do not know how to connect to phpmyadmin in another server...

Comment: If you have one database server you just need to connect to that one server since all phpmyadmin is a user interface for mysql. It doesn't need to know or care about your web servers.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm sorry my English is not good, how to setting `DB_HOST` instead `localhost` ?

Comment: Just change it to the name of your database server. That's it.

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you so much for answers, I update post, after change setting then not work connection to remote database...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50892/discussion-between-shayvard-and-john-conde).

Comment: You'll need to allow remote connection through your control panel or ssh

Comment: @AbuNooh Thank you, but i need create user in phpmyadmin in database server To be connected to this server to other servers. how to create this user?

Comment: Everything is done in the control panel or via ssh. Phpmyadmin is just a client, you'll need a user to access it anyway. Which control panel do you have?

Comment: @AbuNooh I just use Ubuntu 16.04 OS and LAMP with phpmyadmin in servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Create the remote connection

To create a remote connection:

1. On your database server, as a user with `root` privileges, open your MySQL configuration file.

   To locate it, enter the following command:

   `mysql --help`

   The location displays similar to the following:

   `Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`
2. Search the configuration file for `bind-address`.

   If it exists, change the value as follows.

   If it doesn’t exist, add it anywhere except the `[mysqld]` section.

   `bind-address = 192.168.19.33`
3. Save your changes to the configuration file and exit the text editor.
4. Restart the MySQL service: `service mysql restart`

---

### Grant access to a database user

To enable your web node to connect to the database server, you must grant a web node database user access to the database on the remote server.

This example grants the `root` database user full access to the database on the remote host.

To grant access to a database user:

1. Log in to the database server.
2. Connect to the MySQL database as the `root` user.
3. Enter the following command:

   `GRANT ALL ON website.* TO username@192.168.19.33 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

---

### Verify database access

On your web node host, enter the following command to verify the connection works:

`mysql -u username -h 192.168.19.41 -p`

If the MySQL monitor displays as follows, the database is ready for use by the website:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 213
Server version: 5.6.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

---

*Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/mysql_remote.html*